# Store API Rest response in entry form with PHP

Tags: php, channel-form, channel-entries-api

I'm trying to save an API Rest response in entry with PHP. This is the functional PHP script:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
   channel="products" 
   limit="1"
   require_entry="yes"
   entry_id="{segment_3}"
}
<?php

/**
 * Ensure that you have cURL installed by uncommenting
 * ;extension=php_curl.dll
 * in your php.ini
 */

$url = "https://api.**************";

{product_uploaded_model}
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/models/uploads/products/';
$filename = "{file_name}";
$tags = "{author} {file_id}";
$description = "{title}";
{/product_uploaded_model}
$token_api = "*********************";
$title = "{title}";
$private = 1;
$password = "****";

$data = array(
    "title" => $title,
    "description" => $description,
    "fileModel" => "@".$path.$filename,
    "filenameModel" => $filename,
    "tags" => $tags,
    "token" => $token_api,
    "private" => $private,
    "password" => $password
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $response;

?>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The server's response is like this

```
{"result": {"id": "32c45b4fe5b74420a53ee8e76c247837"}, "success": true}
```

Now i need to put the "id" in a entry's field with this in single entry template:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="*****" return="*****/ENTRY_ID" entry_id="{segment_3}"}

{field:product_id}

{/exp:channel:form}
```

Extrapolating the id from the response and putting it in the field, and save the form.

The question is: How can I extrapolate the id from the response? How can I put in `{field:product_id}`? How can I save the form and redirect to another page?

Answer (score 1):

This StackOverflow answer shows how to extract a variable from a JSON string:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10689950/135935

Then echo that variable inside the exp:channel:form tag into a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $ID ?>">
```